# ajax inside addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is very simple but I am missing something here and could not figure out. I have a submit button with an addEventListener so when you click, it will call to php file. However, this is what i get

> {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

but it works if i place ajax outside of addEventListener. I am so confused

**index.html**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: {'user_id': '123213'},
            complete: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        })
    })
});
```

**index.php**

```
echo json_encode("got to php file!!!");
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? Do you see the request and response in the Network tab?

Comment: You should call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal form submission. Or change the button to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why don't you use `.click()`?

Comment: Also, it would be semantically more correct to listen submit event of the form instead of a click of an arbitrary button. It would also execute the handler in a case ENTER was pressed on a text input and some other cases the form would be submitted without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){               // Click handler
        $.get('index.php', 
            {'user_id': '123213'},           // Data payload
            function(resp) {                 // Response callback
                alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
            });
        return false;                        // Prevent default action
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: {'user_id': '123213'},
        })
         .done(function(data) {
           console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function(msg){
            console.log("error");
        });
    })
});
```

Try this it will work

Comment: What is the difference? Attaching the listener wih jQuery doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Some times addEventListener doesn't work on various browsers i faced this issue while using google maps so mostly the problem is with "addEventListener" have you tried with jquery(my method)?

Comment: But the problem lies on the default action of the submit button, the form will be submitted anyway, and server will response with a new page.

Comment: No difference to OP's original code yet, the result is the same, a new page will be loaded.